# Golang-too many arguments

Tags: go

I try to test it,but wrong.

https://github.com/awesome-cmd/dchat/blob/3cf074d33e6be93596ba8484eff4a5152dd1307b/client/spi_test.go#L10

```golang
package server

import "testing"

func TestRun(t *testing.T) {
    Run([]string{"3333"})
}
```

`vscode` return :

```json
{
    "resource": "GitHub/dchat/client/spi_test.go",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#2",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "too many arguments",
    "source": "compiler",
    "startLineNumber": 10,
    "startColumn": 6,
    "endLineNumber": 10,
    "endColumn": 6
}
```

Please help me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your `Run()` does not have any parameters defined.
Try `func Run(list []string)`

Good job on writing tests for your project.